# Activity started from background in sleep does not appear

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-wake-lock

In my sipApp I've got a Service running in background, waiting for incoming calls.
On IncomingCall I try to start an Activity showing the call:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InCallActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
    startActivity(intent);
```

which works well in most cases. InCallActivity comes up and turns on screen and starting wakelock.

But in some cases, when device is in deep sleep and a call is incoming, the service is triggered correctly. The logs telling that it's building up the intent and starting it, but it ends up starting the default HomeActivity and the screen stays black instead of showing InCallActivity. 
Seconds later InCallActivity seems to be cleaned up without ever showed up.

```
10:41:06.809  9711  9741 D CallClient: onCallControllerChanged: CS_INCOMING listener: 1
10:41:06.989  9711  9741 I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.company.product.brand time:8047180
10:41:06.989   830  1228 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x34000004 cmp=com.company.product.brand/com.company.product.call.InCallActivity_ (has extras)} from uid 12231 on display 0
10:41:07.039   830   830 V ActivityManager: Display changed displayId=0
10:41:07.149  9711  9711 D MyVoip: ! onActivityStarted: com.company.product.home.HomeActivity_@14ddfbae
10:41:07.149  9711  9711 D HomeActivity: onResume
10:41:07.149  9711  9711 D MyVoip: ! onActivityResumed: com.company.product.home.HomeActivity_@14ddfbae
[...]
10:41:18.715   830   968 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{1ba876d u0 com.company.product.brand/com.company.product.call.InCallActivity_ t3206}
```

so the InCallActivity is not even created, so even that line:

```
07:39:49.648 D/MyVoip(17451): ! onActivityCreated: com.company.product.call.InCallActivity_@cffb29b
```

is missing in that case

any ideas about that ?